# How do I get the combobox value?

Tags: c#, subsonic, combobox

I usually do web programming but have a requirement for a windows form in this project I'm working on now.

I'm using SubSonic to get a list of jobs and load a combobox:

```
JobCollection jobs = new JobCollection().Load();
cboJobs.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboJobs.ValueMember = "Id";
cboJobs.DataSource = jobs;
```

When the user selects an item and clicks the search button I need to query the database using the job "Id" field.

```
TransactionCollection transactions = new TransactionCollection();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTransactionId.Text))
{
    transactions.Where("id", txtTransactionId.Text);
}
else
{
    transactions.Where("raw_data", Comparison.Like, "%" + txtFind.Text + "%");     
}
transactions.Where("job_id", Convert.ToInt32(cboJobs.SelectedItem));
transactions.Load();
```

The line that is having the problem is the one that goes "Convert.ToInt32(cboJobs.SelectedItem)".

How do I get the job id versus the name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look at the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property of your combobox.  You set the ValueMember to the ID, so the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) should contain the correct value.

Answer (score 3):

You have already gotten (a good) answer, but I thought it might be in place to point this out anyway: in your application's combo box, each item will actually be a full Job object, not only a string representation of one. So the `SelectedItem` property will return the Job object that is currently selected in the ComboBox. You can access any of its members simply by casting it to Job:

```
Job currentJob = cboJobs.SelectedItem as Job;
if (currentJob != null)
{
    // here you can access currentJob.Name, currentJob.Id or any other member
}
```

Comment: thanks, that is a good answer.  I missed the part about casting it to job.  Thanks.